# MS Access: Use VBA to Change Query using Multi-Select List Box

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to do a query that changes based on the selection of a multi-select list box.

My code works fine for 1 item, but if you try to select multiple items it does not work properly.

```
Private Sub Toggle7_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = Application.CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("SSSBasic")
Dim Criteria1 As String

Dim strList As String
Dim FstrList As String
Dim varSelected As Variant

'Criteria1 = Me.List_Group

Dim ctl As Control

Set ctl = Me!List_Group
  If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You haven't selected anything"
  Else
    For Each varSelected In ctl.ItemsSelected
      strList = strList & ctl.ItemData(varSelected) & " Or "
    Next varSelected
    FstrList = Left$(strList, Len(strList) - 4)
    'MsgBox "You selected the following items:" & vbCrLf & FstrList
  End If


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SSSTable WHERE (SSSTable.Group = """ & FstrList & """)"

qdf.SQL = strSQL

DoCmd.OpenQuery "SSSBasic"

End Sub
```

When I select Proc and Non-Proc from list box, the code will run, but I get zero records. This is what the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM SSSTable
WHERE (((SSSTable.Group)="Proc Or Non-Proc"));
```

I cannot figure out how to get it to work...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have to repeat the field in each conditional, `where x=y or x=z`, or consider using the `In()` function. In both cases you need to be careful to construct a valid WHERE clause.

Comment: Andy, thank you for your quick response. I don't follow what you mean though. How do I do the [Where x=y or z=z] thing?